# Why is my Jasper Report displaying several null values?

Tags: java, database, jasper-reports, h2

I know that my Jasper Report is reading from my database properly, because it has the same amount of rows as my database. However, it is filling in all of the parameters with "null". Why is it doing this?

My code:

```
Connection connection;
    Statement stmt;
    ResultSet rs;

    try {

        String query = "SELECT CertificateCode, FirstName, LastName, IssueDate, ExpirationDate, Used FROM giftcertificates";
        //System.out.println("Query created. Connecting to driver...");
        Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
        //System.out.println("Connected to driver. Establishing connection to database...");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:./GiftCertificateManagerDatabase;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE");
        //System.out.println("Database connection established. Creating statement...");
        stmt = connection.createStatement();
        //System.out.println("Statement created. Executing query...");
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        //System.out.println("Query executed. Creating data source with result set...");
        JRResultSetDataSource rsdt = new JRResultSetDataSource(rs);
        //System.out.println("Jasper Report data source created.");
        //System.out.println("Creating JasperReport and JasperPrint...");
        JasperReport jasperReport;
        JasperPrint jasperPrint;
        //System.out.println("JasperReport and JasperPrint created. Compiling report...");

        jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("Reports/GiftCertificateReport.jrxml");
        //System.out.println("Report compiled. Filling report with appropriate information...");
        jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, new HashMap(), rsdt);
        //System.out.println("Report filled. Creating viewer...");
        JasperViewer view = new JasperViewer(jasperPrint);
        //System.out.println("Viewer created. Preparing to display...");
        view.setVisible(true);
        //System.out.println("Viewer displayed. Preparing to close connection...");
        System.out.println(rs);
        connection.close();
        //System.out.println("Connection closed.");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException | JRException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I guess you are using a different (new, empty) database. Do you completely understand what `jdbc:h2:./GiftCertificateManagerDatabase` means? It means relative to the current working directory. I suggest to try using an absolute path, for example `jdbc:h2:/data/GiftCertificateManagerDatabase`.

Comment: No, I know exactly what that statement means. And that is the directory that I use to create and store the database, so I should be able to read it from the same directory.

Comment: In addition to that, I KNOW that it is properly reading from the database, because it's pulling in the same amount of null rows that the database contains.

Comment: when you use empty database as depicted by @ThomasMueller then it does not matter about the number of null rows it is fetching.It just replaces the values to be represented  with null for you,there is no fetching happening actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that Jasper is filling all parameters with null because you are passing an empty map to the fill method:

```
jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, new HashMap(), rsdt);
```

You have to fill that HashMap with the parameters you want.

[JasperFillManager.fillReport apidoc](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperFillManager.html#fillReport%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.util.Map,%20net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource%29)

Comment: Thank you for that answer. So, HashMaps are something I know absolutely nothing about. How do I fill a HashMap with the information from my database?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/ You have to call the put method with the parameter name and the parameter value you recover from database.

Comment: I tried to do that. When I did, it only allowed me to insert one record. Then, my report displayed a record from the database, but it only displayed a SINGLE record. See my new question here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26835610/how-do-i-fill-my-hashmap-with-information-from-my-database-and-then-add-it-to-m]

Comment: Your answer was somewhat helpful, so I have marked it as accepted. If you wouldn't mind referring to my other question, that would be awesome. Thank you for the help.