# How do I fill my HashMap with information from my database, and then add it to my Jasper Report?

Tags: java, sql, database, loops, jasper-reports

I am trying to get my HashMap parameters to be populated with information from my database. I have created a SQL query that retrieves the information, and a ResultSet to display the information. I then use the ResultSet to break the information down in a way that will allow me to assign each value to a string. Here is my current code:

```
    Connection connection;
    Statement stmt;
    ResultSet rs;

    try {

        Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:./GiftCertificateManagerDatabase;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE");
        String query = "SELECT CertificateCode, FirstName, LastName, IssueDate, ExpirationDate, Used FROM giftcertificates";
        stmt = connection.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        JRResultSetDataSource rsdt = new JRResultSetDataSource(rs);
        JasperReport jasperReport;
        JasperPrint jasperPrint;

        jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("Reports/GiftCertificateReport.jrxml");
        HashMap parameters = new HashMap();

        rs.next();

        String CertificateCode = rs.getString("CertificateCode");
        String FirstName = rs.getString("FirstName");
        String LastName = rs.getString("LastName");
        String IssueDate = rs.getString("IssueDate");
        String ExpirationDate = rs.getString("ExpirationDate");
        String Used = rs.getString("Used");

        parameters.put("CertificateCode", CertificateCode);
        parameters.put("FirstName", FirstName);
        parameters.put("LastName", LastName);
        parameters.put("IssueDate", IssueDate);
        parameters.put("ExpirationDate", ExpirationDate);
        parameters.put("Used", Used);

        jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, rsdt);

        JasperViewer view = new JasperViewer(jasperPrint);

        view.setVisible(true);

        System.out.println(rs);
        connection.close();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException | JRException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
```

As you can see, I have used `rs.next();` to go to the first row of the database. It pulls the information in, and is actually sent to my report, which is great. It shows up on my report twice, however. Here is how my report looks (click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8manJ.png) for larger image):

[image: Jasper Report That is Printed]

Here is my JRXML code:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report name" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="535" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="29a25e63-6738-4f28-a9b1-84d9571ae46e">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <parameter name="CertificateCode" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="FirstName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="LastName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="IssueDate" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="ExpirationDate" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="Used" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="bb628493-cab6-4d39-acff-79669009ac6b"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Certificate Code]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="2c18a226-2bdf-45e1-b286-f7795cf1d17f"/>
                <text><![CDATA[First Name]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="200" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="e6b35970-0592-4d97-a054-fb0c65244618"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Last Name]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="300" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="ee345d19-12f4-4ea7-a9d9-924c50904cb9"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Issue Date]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="400" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="c5d69f5e-e716-4393-9815-d9cee8bab88b"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Expiration Date]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="500" y="0" width="55" height="20" uuid="9760f598-6e30-45ad-9d05-2696f6d45c8e"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Used?]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="34b20574-2e15-41c6-928d-2dc52b9c4e7e"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{CertificateCode}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="1652ab96-50cd-4ce3-84b1-83bf074b480c"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{FirstName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="200" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="bcfec07b-d07d-474b-a397-781b9ce0254f"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{LastName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="300" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="cdd427e7-b1cf-4ed3-9cfe-8a13e71c0e0d"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{IssueDate}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="400" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="1f64f071-8d53-4de2-be05-23e78753f467"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{ExpirationDate}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="500" y="0" width="55" height="20" uuid="38402e3c-3279-4a76-85f8-0266d77e34e1"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{Used}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>`

Here is the image of my iReport designer (click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5MDo.png) for larger image):

[image: iReport Designer Screen]

I obviously need to use a while loop, such as `while (rs.next()) { }`, but where do I put it, and what code do I put inside of the loop, in order to get all of the rows from the database to be inserted into the report?

As always, thank you in advance for any helpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<?> list=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
while(rs.hasNext()){
    rs.next();
    HashMap<String,String> parameters=new HashMap<>();

    String CertificateCode = rs.getString("CertificateCode");
    String FirstName = rs.getString("FirstName");
    String LastName = rs.getString("LastName");
    String IssueDate = rs.getString("IssueDate");
    String ExpirationDate = rs.getString("ExpirationDate");
    String Used = rs.getString("Used");

    parameters.put("CertificateCode", CertificateCode);
    parameters.put("FirstName", FirstName);
    parameters.put("LastName", LastName);
    parameters.put("IssueDate", IssueDate);
    parameters.put("ExpirationDate", ExpirationDate);
    parameters.put("Used", Used);

  list.add(parameters);

}
```

Result;

[

{Certificatecode:lskff,Firstname:asdkff,lastname:lsdkfs,issuedate:sdjflksf,expirationdate:lsdfjlsdf,used:skdfjl},

{Certificatecode:lskff,Firstname:asdkff,lastname:lsdkfs,issuedate:sdjflksf,expirationdate:lsdfjlsdf,used:skdfjl},

{Certificatecode:lskff,Firstname:asdkff,lastname:lsdkfs,issuedate:sdjflksf,expirationdate:lsdfjlsdf,used:skdfjl}

]

Comment: The fillReport method will not allow me to use the list. I have to use a HashMap for the second parameter. How would I use the HashMap to fill the report. If I put values into the HashMap, it will only store one value per key. I need to insert multiple rows into my HashMap.

Comment: What you've done here would be handy, if I was simply displaying the data back to the user, for example. However, I have to insert this data in to JasperReport. The `JasperFillManager.fillReport()` requires the parameters of JasperReport, HashMap, and data source. My data source is working properly, because it's pulling information from my database. And my JasperReport is working properly, because it has to compile the report before it can be displayed. It's the HashMap that is causing issues. How might I add several rows of data to the report using a HashMap?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing the report detail provided by JRDataSource with the parameter map.

The parameter map is a set of key-values you can display on the report.

The JRDataSource  is useful to fill the detail data.

[What is the difference between variable, parameter and field in JasperReports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041137/what-is-the-difference-between-variable-parameter-and-field-in-jaspersoft-irepo)

Comment: When I use fields in my report (as $F{CertificateCode}), it tells me that the field was not found. Using parameters allows the report to be populated with data, and I know that it's pulling from the database properly (you can see that in the image that I attached in my question). I just don't know how to loop through the data and add ALL of it (rather than just one record) to the report.

Comment: Did you compose the report (jrxml) using iReport?

Comment: Yes, using the iReport plug-in for NetBeans.

Comment: If you run the report from iReport, it fills the fields in the detail?

Comment: If I preview the report, it asks me to enter each parameter, as a test for the preview. And then it shows a preview with just the one record.

Comment: I'm trying to pass the information from my H2 database to the Jasper Report from within my Java code.

Comment: please post the jrxml or a link to it. It contains fields or parameters in the detail?

Comment: Yes. I will post a picture of the iReport designer screen in my question, and I will add the jrxml code.

Comment: You are using parameters in the detail, I think this is the problem. Take a look at this tutorial https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/designing-report and get a running report in iReport extracting data from your database, then you can use it in your java code.

Comment: The first problem with that is that I am using an H2 database, and I'm not sure how to connect an H2 database to iReport. I can't find it in the list. The second problem is that if, in the future, I want to order the reports by a specific column, I don't know if I would be able to do that. The link that you sent me to won't get me anywhere, mostly due to the first problem.

Comment: Plus, if I am going to use the Jasper Report fill manager, parameters are required to fill the report, so seems to be my only option if I want to fill the report from my Java code.

Comment: You have to add the H2 driver to iReport, see https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/538350/adding-jdbc-driver In the other side, if you need to order the report you can do it in java, using a JRBeanArrayDataSource for instance. But before, I think it´s easier if you get a running jrxml.

Comment: Okay, so I will be using a SQL query in the JRXML, instead of in my Java code, correct?

Comment: All you have directed me to is a question. There are no useful or helpful answers regarding the process for adding my H2 driver to the iReport plug-in. How do I do that?

Comment: Okay, so that printed out my report great. But I have two problems... 1) Now, I need to figure out how to do that from my Java code. And 2) I had to use an absolute path to connect to the database, which will not work if my application is installed on another computer.

Comment: Now, try to modify your java code, you can do it the same way you last post or use: JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parameters, connection);

Comment: Nothing has changed between the two.